# .net & Excel - From Office 2007 to 2013

Tags: .net, excel, office-interop, office-2007, office-2013

so, our IT department upgraded everybody from Office 2007 to Office 2013, and many of my hard work has to be redone. (VS 2013 Express, framework 4.5)

The error I am getting is:

"Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00020846-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Interface not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040155”

I understand that this is caused by the interop new dll version etc, but I have spent hours and hours reading about it without finding anything useful. It crashes the first "xlws.Cells(i, j) = dt.Rows(i - 1).Item(j-1).ToString()"

I did find some workarounds and finally managed to get it almost working, but it feels so much more complicated than it used to be I am still struggling with the ranges and sorting.

If someone could share a simple code allowing to:

- Open Excel
- Create a worksheet
- Export values from a datatable to the worksheet
- Define a range
- Sort the range

I would be really thankful!

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.application")
xlApp.Visible = False
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)

Dim myrange As Excel.Range
Dim xlws As Excel.Worksheet
xlws = xlwb.Worksheets.Add(After:=xlwb.Worksheets(xlwb.Worksheets.Count))
xlws.Name = “name”

For i = 1 To dt.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To dt.Columns.Count
        xlws.Cells(i, j) = dt.Rows(i - 1).Item(j-1).ToString()
    Next
Next

xlws.Columns.AutoFit()

myrange = xlws.UsedRange
myrange.Select()
myrange.Sort(Key1:=myrange.Range("M1"), Order1:=Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,     Orientation:=Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns)
myrange = xlws.Cells(2, 1)
myrange.Select()

xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete()
xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Delete()
xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Delete()
xlWorkBook.Worksheets("name").select()

xlWorkBook.SaveAs(folder_str & Format(Now, "MMddyyyy").ToString & " - " & “name” & ".xlsx")

xlWorkBook.Close()
xlApp.Quit()

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlws)
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook)
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194567(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Worksheet class returns an instance of the Range class. So you are trying to assign a text to a range object which is not possible.

In general, to avoid such issue I'd suggest breaking the chain of calls (multiple dots in the single line of code) and declaring each property or method call on a separate line of code.

You may find the [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Visual Basic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/219151) and [Excel Automation from Ron de Bruin](http://www.rondebruin.nl) links helpful. There you will find a sample code.

Comment: The msdn link isn't useful, because the explanation and code example is exactly what I was using with Office 2007. Looks like after Office 2010 everything changed...but I can't find a simple msdn page like this one related to Office 2010/2013. Very frustrating...

Comment: I don't see any breaking changes between these versions. What changes are you talking about?

Comment: For example the only way I can make the first line to work is by changing it to oSheet.Name = "TEST"
        oWB.Worksheets(oSheet.Name).Range("A" & 1) = "First Name"

Comment: For office 2010 and 2013 the object libraries are 14 and 15...which they don't mention in the article.

Comment: Yes, articles are quite old, but nothing has changed since that time except vserion numbers as you noticed.

Comment: Thank you. I realized that changing **Dim xlws As Excel.Worksheet** to **Dim xlws As Object** makes the **.cells(1,1).value** work...I'll keep digging. Thanks for your help